# A PushBox Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, visual

Use only five sliding block moves to get the piece labeled T to the lower
right corner. A move is one piece moved along any path.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 to bottom left.
>  T to right.
>  2 to middle top side.
>  3 to top left.
>  T to bottom right.

Answer (score 6):

Simlar to @Bass's answer, but this one is animated.

> [image]